# Where was the Caretaker's farm scenes filmed for "Star Trek: Voyager"?

Tags: star-trek, film-location, star-trek-voyager

In *Star Trek Voyager*'s pilot episode "Caretaker", the crew of the *Voyager* is transferred to a holographic simulation of a farm. I could not find any information about the filming location of the farm scenes.

Where was that scene shot?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Filming_locations Quite possible it was on the backlot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any mention of the location anywhere, but using a little google-fu searching for film location farmhouses near LA, [Paddison Farmhouse](http://www.paddisonfarm.com/) stands out as pretty darn close.   The wrap-around porch, the green roof, the wooden decorations, the gazebo, the fence all look spot on.  The Red barn(s) aren't spot on but are close and they may have been touched-up since 1995.

Answer (score -2):

> The scenes of the underground court on the Ocampa homeworld in the pilot episode "Caretaker" were filmed at the Los Angeles Convention Center. The scenes on the planet's surface, including the *Kazon-Ogla village*, were filmed *at the El Mirage Dry Lake Bed in the High Desert of Southern California*.

[Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Filming_locations)

Comment: This fails to answer the question in anyway; it asks about the holographic farm on the Caretaker's array, not anything on Ocampa.